# MySQL throws an error when receiving my query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have to access a MySQL database that looks like this:

```
LOG_ID  KEY      TARGET        CREATOR    
1       okaytest 297d09d5-55fe faec09c0-159e
```

I can do the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM DATABASE WHERE LOG_ID=1
```

This would return me the column correctly.
But I can't do the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM DATABASE WHERE KEY='okaytest'
```

I believe that there might be a problem with the word KEY being a reserved keyword in MySQL, but I have to access that specific database, I can't change it's name and I must select it from the key

Comment: don't use [(My)SQL Keywords and or Reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) best is to prefix as in `log_key` for example, as with the provided answer you would need to use backticks always now trust me it quickly becomes irritating to type those backticks

Comment: Sometimes we have no choice but to work with the reserved words.  There are many things far more irritating than typing a few extra keystrokes.  Let it go..

Comment: @alexherm nothing is more irritating to find/debug queries which don't work because of missing backticks..  *"Sometimes we have no choice but to work with the reserved words."* Also other option in MySQL which is much better is always using full quantified table names or aliases like `SELECT * FROM t WHERE t.KEY='okaytest'` see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ez2KpngMAsgDiwukXyMS2z/0) then MySQL knows `KEY` is a column of the table `t` here and not a keyword...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like below by using the backtick `

```
SELECT * FROM DATABASE WHERE `KEY`='okaytest'
```

actually for reserve word you have to use this backtick otherwise it will thorow error [here is the reserve word list](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)

another options better not to use reserve word or incase of necessary you have use it by using backtick

Comment: Awesome thanks for the result! I'll approve your answer in 10 minutes when StackOverflow allows me to do so.

Comment: It would be NICE to actually tell the OP Why they need to do this in this case i.e. MySQL reserved words